# Why does Meteor /Mupx deployment fail on one computer but not another?

Tags: meteor, mup

I am able to deploy to digital ocean from one computer, but when I try to make a change and deploy from another laptop I get this error.  The configuration on both is almost identical except the start.sh file lives in two separate places.

```
Verifying deployment: FAILED

-----------------------------------STDERR-----------------------------------
package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No description
npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No README data
npm WARN cannot run in wd meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 node npm-rebuild.js (wd=/bundle/bundle/programs/server)
=> Starting meteor app on port:80

assert.js:93
  throw new assert.AssertionError({
        ^
AssertionError: "undefined" === "function"
    at wrapPathFunction (/bundle/bundle/programs/server/mini-files.js:77:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/bundle/bundle/programs/server/mini-files.js:108:24)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/bundle/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:9:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)

=> Redeploying previous version of the app

-----------------------------------STDOUT-----------------------------------

To see more logs type 'mup logs --tail=50'

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

mup logs --tail=50
    loaded mup.js from /Users/...

```
1 Validation Errors
  - "meteor.env.ROOT_URL" with value "app.com" fails to match the valid url with "http://" or "https://" pattern

If you think there is a bug in the mup.js validator, please
create an issue at https://github.com/zodern/meteor-up
```

mupx logs --tail=50

```
Meteor Up: Production Quality Meteor Deployments
------------------------------------------------
Configuration file : mup.json
Settings file      : settings.json

[45.55.131.119]     at wrapPathFunction (/bundle/bundle/programs/server/mini-files.js:77:10)
[45.55.131.119]     at Object.<anonymous> (/bundle/bundle/programs/server/mini-files.js:108:24)
[45.55.131.119]     at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
[45.55.131.119]     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
[45.55.131.119]     at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
[45.55.131.119]     at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
[45.55.131.119]     at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
[45.55.131.119]     at require (module.js:380:17)
[45.55.131.119]     at Object.<anonymous> (/bundle/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:9:13)
[45.55.131.119]     at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
[45.55.131.119] npm WARN deprecated This version of npm lacks support for important features,
[45.55.131.119] npm WARN deprecated such as scoped packages, offered by the primary npm
[45.55.131.119] npm WARN deprecated registry. Consider upgrading to at least npm@2, if not the
[45.55.131.119] npm WARN deprecated latest stable version. To upgrade to npm@2, run:
[45.55.131.119] npm WARN deprecated
[45.55.131.119] npm WARN deprecated   npm -g install npm@latest-2
[45.55.131.119] npm WARN deprecated
[45.55.131.119] npm WARN deprecated To upgrade to the latest stable version, run:
[45.55.131.119] npm WARN deprecated
npm WARN deprecated   npm -g install npm@latest
npm WARN deprecated
[45.55.131.119] npm WARN deprecated (Depending on how Node.js was installed on your system, you
[45.55.131.119] => Starting meteor app on port:80
[45.55.131.119] npm WARN deprecated may need to prefix the preceding commands with `sudo`, or if
npm WARN deprecated on Windows, run them from an Administrator prompt.)
npm WARN deprecated
npm WARN deprecated If you're running the version of npm bundled with
npm WARN deprecated Node.js 0.10 LTS, be aware that the next version of 0.10 LTS
npm WARN deprecated will be bundled with a version of npm@2, which has some small
npm WARN deprecated backwards-incompatible changes made to `npm run-script` and
npm WARN deprecated semver behavior.
npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No description
npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No README data
npm WARN cannot run in wd meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 node npm-rebuild.js (wd=/bundle/bundle/programs/server)

assert.js:93
  throw new assert.AssertionError({
        ^
AssertionError: "undefined" === "function"
    at wrapPathFunction (/bundle/bundle/programs/server/mini-files.js:77:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/bundle/bundle/programs/server/mini-files.js:108:24)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
[45.55.131.119]     at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
[45.55.131.119]     at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
[45.55.131.119]     at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/bundle/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:9:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
```

Comment: This generally happens when the node versions are incompatible between the two systems. You sure that both the systems have same version of Node and npm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This generally happens when the node versions are incompatible between the two systems. You sure that both the systems have same version of Node and npm.